# Python os.path.exists() ignore part of file name

Tags: python, file, operating-system

I have a directory that looks like the following:

```
> myDirectory
    > L1.zip
    > L2_abc.zip
```

I want to search through the directory to return if a file exists, but I will only have the first part of the zip file name (L1 or L2). How would I go about checking if the file exists?

The results should look a little like the following:

```
>>> file_exists("L1")
true 
>>> file_exists("L2")
true
```

I am currently just using `os.path.exists()`, but I don't know how to ignore the `_abc` part of the file name.

Comment: [`glob.glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob).

Comment: Would you like to return `True` just in case `L1.zip` exists, or any file starting with L1, like, e.g., `L1.txt`?

Comment: @Mureinik Any files is fine, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use listdir and do a custom check. Here's one way that only matches if the file/dir starts with L2

```
matches = [f for f in os.listdir() if f.startswith("L2")]
print(matches)
```

Comment: my search parameter is actually a fairly long ID. Thanks for the solution; it also avoids another import. `glob` may be useful in different cases.

Answer (score 2):

Using [`glob`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob), and checking if the result output is empty or not should do the trick:

```
from glob import glob

def file_exists(filename):
    return bool(glob(filename + '.*'))
```

Comment: you don't use glob in your example.

Comment: @Daniel arg! forgot the most important part! Edited and fixed, thanks for noticing.

Comment: This also works for testing directory names.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pathlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html):

```
from pathlib import Path

def file_exists(prefix):
    return any(Path("myDirectory").glob(prefix + "*"))
```